# Does google closure compiler support ECMAScript modules? JSC_INVALID_MODULE_PATH error

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Here is a simple [example](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer) using [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), *buffer.js*:

```js
import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer';

// Creates a zero-filled Buffer of length 10.
const buf1 = Buffer.alloc(10);
```

Compiled it:

```bash
# google-closure-compiler --js buffer.js --language_in ECMASCRIPT_2019
buffer.js:1:0: ERROR - [JSC_INVALID_MODULE_PATH] Invalid module path "node:buffer" for resolution mode "BROWSER"
  1| import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer';
     ^

1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Also:

```bash
# google-closure-compiler --js buffer.js --module_resolution=NODE
buffer.js:1:0: ERROR - [JSC_JS_MODULE_LOAD_WARNING] Failed to load module "node:buffer"
  1| import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer';
     ^
```

Works with [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) though:

```js
const { Buffer } = require('node:buffer');

// Creates a zero-filled Buffer of length 10.
const buf1 = Buffer.alloc(10);
```

Result:

```bash
# google-closure-compiler --js buffer-cjs.js
const {Buffer}=require("node:buffer"),buf1=Buffer.alloc(10);
```

Would appreciate any clarity on whether ESM is supported, and if so, how to enable it. Tried other things, looked up the [documentation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler#google-closure-compiler) and searched online, but no solution found.